# tCommon imports cython

Tags: python, cython, python-import

I have a file structure

```
[CODE DIR]
- foo_1.pyx
- foo_1.pxd
- ...
- foo_n.pyx
```

with most of the files sharing some import statements, i.e. `from cython cimport [somePackage]`.

## Problem

I want to have one common file `foo_common.pyx` that contains shared imports across the `foo_x.pyx` files without copying most of them over.  `foo_common.pyx`  would contain for instance

```
[foo_common.pyx]
cimport numpy as np
from cython.parallel cimport prange 
....
```

I tried stacking some common definitions in a `pyx` or `pxd` file but cython only seems to see class or other definitions but not. Is it possible in cython to have a common 'header-like' file in which import statements are read?

### Clarification

I have got definitions file `definitions.pxd` :

```
[definitions.pxd]
cimport cython
```

i have some other file `foo_1.pyx`

```
[foo_1.pyx]
from definitions cimport *

@cython.cdivision(True)
cdef doing_something (int x):
     return x
```

will error stating that a `cdef function cannot take arbitrary decorators`.
Changing the `cimport` to `include` will run flawlessly. Why is this behavior different?

In hindsight I found my answer regarding what can be in `pxd` for sharing definitions:

`It cannot contain the implementations of any C or Python functions, or any Python class definitions, or any executable statements.` from [here](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html). It seems like include would be the way to go as the cimport / import statements ignores any other definition; only C/C++ relevent defintions.

Comment: `from cython cimport ...`? You aren't actually naming your module `cython` are you? Because that's immediately going to conflict with the Cython compiler and it's directives and so forth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cython has two ways to share information between multiple `pyx`-files:

- using  `cimport`-mechanism is the python-like, more sophisticated way similar to `import`.
- using `include` corresponds to the lowly C-ish way of just dumping the content of a header into another files, i.e. `#include <xxx>`.

What you are looking for is the second option. For example after defining `common.pxi` as:

```
# common.pxi
from libc.stdint cimport  int64_t   
ctypedef double float64
...
```

it can be used in different pyx-files, `a.pyx`:

```
# a.pyx:
include "common.pxi"  # definitions of float64_t, int64_t are now known

# float64_t, int64_t are used:
cdef doit_a(float64_t a, int64_t b):
    ....
```

and `b.pyx`:

```
# b.pyx:
include "common.pxi"  # definitions of float64_t, int64_t are now known

# float64_t, int64_t are used:
cdef doit_a(float64_t a, int64_t b):
    ....
```

While using `pxi`-files for common `typedef` and `cimports`, but also for dividing a pyx-file into multiple subparts, are valid usages - for other scenarios the `pxd`-files are the better option and sometimes the only (sane) option (sharing `cdef`-interface of a `cdef class`).

One advantage of `pxd`-files is more control over what is cimported, similar to `import` one could cimport everything via

```
# definitions are in common.pxd
from common cimport *
```

but there is also the option to cimport only some names.

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I was looking for. What makes `(c)import`  behave diferently? Namely, I had a `common.pxd` that would not load any of the modules from cython, i.e. if `common.pxd` contained some import `from libcpp.vector cimport vector` the other `foo_x.pyx` would not see this import.  Additionally why would `pxd` be a better option?

Comment: @cvanelteren "cimport" corresponds to "import", which also doesn't  drag all names from the imported module into the global namespace. You can however use `from ... cimport *`, see my edit.

Comment: yeah I tried that before posting but it doesn't pull definitions in the same way as include does [see update original post]